# image is not getting resized in css even after using the height and width properties

Tags: html, css

I want my background image to occupy full screen of my browser window but it is not working.I am getting confused about how image works when height and width are adjusted using  two methods mentioned below

1)

```
.background{
width:100%;
height:100%;
```

2. 

```
.background img{
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
```

My html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Plane moving project</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="background">
        
    </div>

    <div class="plane">

    </div>

    <div class="track">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My css:

```
html,body{
    overflow: hidden;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
.background{
    background:url("background.jpg") center no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}  

.background img{
    height:auto;
    width:100%; 
}
```

My output:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/npleg.png

Comment: sorry,I was not aware of this. i thought that caps would increase readability .thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't comment due to lack of reputation.

I think you want to use `background-size:cover;`

Was unable to find the shorthand syntax.

```
.background{
    background:url("background.jpg") center;
    background-size:cover;
/* below will change the height of the .background class elements not the background */
/* height:100%; */
}
```